# how to do routing with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

am working on a rails app where i have two models `products` and `category`
and my category `has_many :products` and my products `belongs_to a category`
so i want to be able to setup my route like where the URL will be like `http://example.com/products/categoryname/product-name`. how can i achieve this. in my routes i have

```
resources :products do
  resources categories
  get ':name', to: 'category#index', as: :category
end
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: i found it easier to achieve through the use of slugs here is a good article on it http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-vanity-urls-in-rails

Comment: your code in `routes.rb` file seems you are trying to generate some Resourceful routes, but your example URL shows something like non-resourceful ! So please update your question with a valid example URL.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this in your `routes.rb`

```
resources :products
get "/products/:category_name/:product_name/" => "products#index"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more difficult than you think, as the URL link doesn't follow 'normal' behaviour.

You don't need to nest your routes in the routes.rb file.  Declaring the relationships will be sufficient.  So just have;

```
resources :products
resources :categories
```

Are you against having 'category_id' versus 'category_name' ... which would be easier.

Otherwise you have to created a 'slug' for a url.  And tell Rails about the slugs etc..    it can get messy.

Answer (score -1):

for anyone having a problem like this, here is how i solve my issue.
i used the friendly id gem then on my routes i have it like

`resources :products`

`get "/products/:id/:id/" => "products#show"`